# Using stringify on JSON object to use in HTML data attribute

Tags: javascript, json, encoding, stringify

I've been looking through the various on posts on stringify but I have been unable to find a solution to my problem.

I'm trying to stringify a JSON object and insert it into the data attribute of a new element in the DOM.

In the example below, if the element is inspected using Chrome and then edit HTML is selected, the output looks like the following:

`<div class="ui-menu-item" data-menu-item="{" title":"this="" is="" a="" test="" for="" \"="" and="" '.="" it="" fails.","url":"some="" url"}"="" id="test">This element contains the data.</div>`

The required result should look like the following I think:

`<div class="ui-menu-item" data-menu-item="{&quot;title&quot;:&quot;this is a test for &quot; and ' it fails.&quot;,&quot;url&quot;:&quot;some url&quot;}" id="test">This element contains the data.</div>`

Note: I know I can use jQuery's data method instead but choosing not to.

```js
  var data = {
    title: 'This is a test for " and \'. It fails.',
   url: 'Some url'
  };

  data = JSON.stringify(data);

  console.log (data);

$(document).ready(function() {
  var tpl = "<div class=\"ui-menu-item\" data-menu-item=\"" + data + "\" id=\"test\">This element contains the data.</div>";
  
  $('body').append(tpl);
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hi Asa, have you try jQuery.data()? it work perfectly for this situations. if you have jquery, use it.[link](https://api.jquery.com/data/)

Comment: @NeoAnderson hi, As I mentioned in the post, I'm aware of it but I'd prefer to keep it in the attribute. The attributes are there on existing elements created server side and I just want to keep everything consistent.

Comment: You could create the `<div>` and then use `setAttribute()` to set the value to the JSON string.

Comment: It seems that you might need to write your own string.replace formula to get rid of the double quotes or other special characters. Is the expectation that you would also be pulling down that JSON again and parsing it for later use in your application?

Comment: if you Insist that dont use .data() . what about use encodeURI and decodeURI. , as one prepare-like function for this problem. you can do this : encodeURI(JSON.stringify(data))

Comment: It doesn't need URI encoding; it's not a URI after all. All it needs is for all the double-quote characters to be replaced with `@quot;`, but that's only necessary if the fragment is to be parsed as HTML.

Comment: It seems the obvious answer is that I should probably just use .data(), but I’ll give creating the div and setting the data attribute a go too.

Comment: Using `.setAttribute()` directly is pretty much exactly as easy and, unlike `.data()`, you'll actually have an attribute in the DOM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
  var data = {
    title: 'This is a test for " and \'. It fails.',
   url: 'Some url'
  };

  data = JSON.stringify(data);

  console.log (data);

$(document).ready(function() {
  var tpl = "<div class=\"ui-menu-item\" id=\"test\">This element contains the data.</div>";
  
  $('body').append(tpl);
  $('#test').attr('data-menu-item', data)
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider inserting a  jQuery object instead of doing all that string escaping work and use `data()` method to pass your object to the element

```js
var data = {
  title: 'This is a test for " and \'. It fails.',
  url: 'Some url'
};


var tpl = $('<div>', {class: "ui-menu-item",id: "test"})
            .text("This element contains the data")
            .data(data); 
            
$('body').append(tpl);

console.log($('#test').data('title'))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'm a big fan of `.data()` but it should be noted that it won't actually *set* the attribute on the DOM node.

Comment: @Pointy found a surprising issue with it also where when used to set in a parent doc you couldn't access it from within an iframe using the iframe version of jQuery global. I always assumed it used Element.dataset in more recent versions but turns out it doesn't. Had to do`window .parent.$(selector).data()` to get it